# Formula field to calculate the percentage of days remaining

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-field, percent

I have a custom formula field where I need to calculate the amount of days in the year * 100 \ 365 = % of days remaining.

I've created the following formula:

`ROUND((365 - (CloseDate - DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 1, 1))) / 365, 2)`

which is not giving me correct result.

Please advise what I need to change in the existing formula to be able to get

`the amount of days in the year * 100 \ 365 = % of days remaining`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula is correct, but you don't need the explicit `ROUND()` call. Just set your field to have the return type Percent, with two decimal places, and use your existing core formula:

```
(365 - (CloseDate - DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 1, 1))) / 365
```

If you load an Opportunity with a Close Date of 2019-09-01 (September 1, the 244th day of 2019), you'll see 33.42% of the year remaining, which is correct:

```
(365 - (2019-01-01 - 2019-01-01)) / 365 = (365 - 243) / 365 = 0.3342
```